# ActiveRecord::Base deprecated destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deprecated

In one of my programs I use a model called User and then use `user = User.create(attr)` where attr are the necessary attributes for this action.  Then to destroy this I use `user.destroy`.  However, I see that in the API Doc the destroy instance method for ActiveRecord::Base is deprecated -- is there a new/better way to go about destroying a model object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been deprecated, it's just been moved. The `destroy` method is now a member of `ActiveRecord::Persistence` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`. However, you still call it the exact same way:

```
user.destroy
```